# How to upload spreadsheet with script and enable triggers remotely?

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I'd like to be able to upload a new spreadsheet to my drive remotely from my server as needed (using Google's [PHP Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php), say), and it to trigger to run once daily at a given time, then read that spreadsheet remotely once a day after the script runs. I want to fully automate this. I don't want to have to manually install the sheet and set up the trigger for each.

The guides, API, tutorials I've found have not been very clear about how to specifically upload a spreadsheet with an associated script and set triggers. Is this possible? And how do I go about it? If there are some good resources I've missed, much appreciate pointing me to them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way yo "upload" a Google spreadsheet from a local server since they are online documents. You could use a template that has an embedded script but the script would require authorization to run so it won't fit your requirement neither.

Why don't you use a standalone script (or an embedded script in a "master sheet") that would do what you need to do in all the spreadsheets you create (or even upload/convert from ods or excel files with data) ?

One single script can access any number of spreadsheets and do about everything an embedded script can do in these sheets while requiring only one single authorization. This script could create the files and work on a daily timer to do the job.

Comment: thanks very much for your suggestions. I wasn't aware you could have a master script that processes multiple sheets (files I hope). I'm looking for some help, perhaps someone who could consult with me for 20-30 minutes to set me on the right path. Perhaps a short call, or a online tutorial or book on the subject. Any?